# how to deploy website with edmx

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

i have just only added `Edmx` file  inside *App_code* folder and it's mapped with database(*sqlexpress*). I am not using `ADO.Net` context DB generator. My website is working successfully in local pc but when website is  hosted in `IIS7` it is not running and can't connect to the database.

Please let me know how to set connection string so that my connection string identify sdl,msdl,msl? Please guide me if i missed anything. It would be better if you have sample website which is hosted in iis.

```
<add name="Entities1" 
  connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.sSystem.csdl|res://*/App_Code.sSystem.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.sSystem.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=server111;Initial Catalog=inventory;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Data Source=localhost;` instead of `Data Source=server111;` in your connection string.